# TO_CHAR is failing in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

Why `TO_CHAR(rln.FECHA_CONSULTA,'dd-MM-yyyy')AS'FECHA_CONSULTA'` is failing when i'm executing this script?

```
SELECT 
rln.CIF_NIF,
rln.MOTIVO,
TO_CHAR(rln.FECHA_CONSULTA,'dd-MM-yyyy') AS 'FECHA_CONSULTA' --fail here
FROM RASTRO_LISTA_NEGRA rln 
WHERE rln.FECHA_CONSULTA >= TO_DATE (CONCAT(TO_CHAR(sysdate-1,'dd/MM/yyyy'),'08:00:00'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

I'm using Oracle

Comment: What does 'failing' mean? Please edit your question to show the full error you get. But - `AS 'FECHA_CONSULTA'` should be `AS "FECHA_CONSULTA"` or just `AS FECHA_CONSULTA`. Single quotes are for string literals, double-quotes are for identifiers.

Comment: have you tried using CAST or CONVERT?

Comment: @Synapsis Why? In Oracle, `CONVERT` changes a string from one character set to another and `CAST` changes data-type neither of them will format the date to the OP's format.

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes are used for string literals. Not for alias names.

So change this

```
AS 'FECHA_CONSULTA' --fail here
```

To this

```
AS "FECHA_CONSULTA" --alright
```

Or this

```
AS FECHA_CONSULTA   --okidoki
```

Also, the `WHERE` clause could be simplified

```
WHERE rln.FECHA_CONSULTA >= (TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) + INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE)
```

Comment: Take care as `AS FECHA_CONSULTA` is ok, but if it contains spaces, it needs to be in quotes like `AS "FECHA CONSULTA". Also, when not on quotes it's always shown as upper case, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly essentially a typo: single quotes are used for [literal values](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-192417E8-A79D-4A1D-9879-68272D925707), double quotes are used for identifiers.

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA):

> ... you represent the name of an object with a quoted identifier or a nonquoted identifier.
>
> - A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.
> - A nonquoted identifier is not surrounded by any punctuation.

So `AS 'FECHA_CONSULTA'` should be `AS "FECHA_CONSULTA"`, or just `AS FECHA_CONSULTA` since the alias identifier doesn't need to be quoted in this case.

But you can also simplify this:

```
TO_DATE (CONCAT(TO_CHAR(sysdate-1,'dd/MM/yyyy'),'08:00:00'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

to:

```
TRUNC(sysdate-1) + INTERVAL '8' HOUR
```

or

```
TRUNC(sysdate-1) + (8/24)
```